# Finding ancestors thought to be from Chalakudy, India?

Tags: 20th-century, india

Only details we know is that my great grandmother was from a rich Ezhava family where her brother (he did not marry, therefore no descendants) did puja in a Sarpakavu, and that my grandfather should have continued it as nephew followed the uncle in the tradition.

We think they were Kalari masters also.

My great grandfather is also from Chalakudy but after my grandfather's birth they moved to Idukki.

Comment: Most probably your ancestors are from Malabar area of Kerala, because at that time most Kalari masters are from Malabar area and there are lot of Sarpakavu in that area.

Answer (score 1):

The only previous question about Kerala (the state in which [Chalakudy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalakudy) is found) was [How can I trace my ancestry in India?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-trace-my-ancestry-in-india) but that does not seem to have anything in common with yours beyond involving the same Indian state.

Consequently, if you have not already done so, perhaps start with the [FamilySearch catalog page on Kerala](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=166859&query=%2Bplace%3A%22India%2C%20Kerala%22).

If that does not help, then by editing your question to provide more details, it may be possible for someone to provide a more specific answer.

As long as the ancestors you are asking about were born more than 100 years ago, and as long as you feel comfortable to do so, you should be able to ask freely about them using their names and dates of birth without compromising our [Privacy Policy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).